# Stripping dry-film photoresist safely at home

Tags: etching

I am trying my hand at dry-film photoresists. I am looking for any hints on how to strip it safely at home.

From what I can gather, stripping dry-film is generally done with 1-4% sodium hydroxide or potassium hydroxide solution.

Are there any alternatives for DIY that are safer to handle? Soaking is isopropanol and acetone left my dry film thoroughly unimpressed...

Comment: What are your concerns about NaOH/KOH? Other than being caustic they are pretty benign and common chemicals.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am mainly concerned with caustic burns, in particular wrt. eye-safety.

Comment: Proper PPE should of course be used, particularly goggles. The alternative is to get it fabbed externally which can be done on a budget now, for example trying pcbshopper. It does add a few weeks into development however.

Comment: Trust me you are not gonna die. And you won't get blind either.

Answer (score 1):

OK I did some research and will answer my own question in case somebody else is looking for some solid data on the health risks.

For the concentrations of sodium hydroxide and potassium hydroxide typically used for photoresist stripping (0.5% - 1%), both substances are classed by the European Union not as "Eye/Skin Corrosive" but merely as "Eye/Skin Irritant":

[Classification of Sodium Hydroxide](https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/cl-inventory-database/-/discli/details/134413), [Classification of Potassium Hydroxide](https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/cl-inventory-database/-/discli/details/128217)

That is not to say they are completely harmless but at least reasonably safe at these low concentrations.

As a side note: Oven cleaners may contain up to 5% sodium hydroxide. They work in a pinch for stripping. Though leaving them too long will dull the copper surface.

Comment: +1 Lye is fairly easily available- on Amazon, and at soapmaking suppliers and even in some hardware stores. Needs to be kept off the skin and chemical rated eye protection is good. It can be neutralized with vinegar.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on type of dry photoresist.
The one I am using requires washing soda (Na2CO3) for developing (dissolving film that was not exposed to UV).

If I want to remove even cured photoresist, I can use stronger solution of washing soda or ethanol for couple of minutes.

I'm using:
DuPont Riston T215 MV3507A
ROHM&HAAS - Dynamask 5000

Comment: What concentration do you use for developing and which concentration do you use for stripping? How long does stripping take with your process? As far as alcohol goes: 30 min of isopropanol did absolutely nothing to my dry film...

Comment: @ARF I'm using 1% solution of washing soda (Na2CO3) for developing (it dissolves film that was not exposed to UV light). Then etching in ferric chloride (FeCl3). Then stripping in ethanol (or stronger solution of washing soda)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the salt & vinegar etching process.  This article seems to cover it pretty well

http://tinkerman.cat/pcb-etching-at-home-using-vinegar/

(I can't be bothered myself and have not tried home etching. I prefer factory made boards with plated thru holes, solder mask, stenciling -> repeatability!)

Comment: Thanks but this is not a process for stripping the photoresist but for etching. These are two different things.